# I need a Java Scanner 'reset' on invalid character fix

Tags: java

I am a new human learning to code!

I had a problem with my Scanner, which is that I need it to 'reset' on an invalid character.

My code:

```
public class Lemonade {

static int m = 150;
private static Scanner scan;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int day = 1;

    for(int gameover = m; gameover > 0; day++) {
    int Random = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    if(Random <= 25) {
        System.out.println("Great Chance!");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    }
    else if(Random <= 50) {
        System.out.println("Good Chance!");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    }
    else if(Random <= 75) {
        System.out.println("Bad Chance!");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    }
    else if(Random <= 100) {
        System.out.println("Awful Chance!");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    }

    int count = 0;

    int none = 0;

    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and " + m + "!");

    count = scan.nextInt();

    if(count >= none && count <= m) {
        System.out.println("You entered " + count + "!");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        day = day + 1;
        m = m - count;
        System.out.println("Day " + day);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and " + m + "."); 
        count = scan.nextInt();
    }

    }
}
}
```

Now is my question how to get this to 'reset' on an invalid character like 'f', as Scanner only accepts numbers.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you need is a call of next(), which reads and discards any String from the Scanner.

Comment: And probably a loop, like `for` or `while`, you just want to read more input until the user types the correct thing.  It's not really a "reset" just keep reading.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then this is something you're looking for,
InputMismatchException will thrown if user enters invaild characters instead of int. You may use looping until the user enters an integer

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;


class Example
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        boolean isProcessed = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = 0;
        while(!isProcessed)
        {

            try
            {
                value = input.nextInt();
        //example  we will now check for the range 0 - 150
        if(value < 0 || value > 150) {
            System.out.println("The value entered is either greater than 150 or may be lesser than 0");
        }
        else isProcessed = true; // If everything is ok, Then stop the loop
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.print(e);
        input.next();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

If this is not you're looking for please let me know!

Comment: This is what I want, but I still have one problem; even if I add **_"  && count < none && count > m"_** to "while", but it still "skips" the "while" when I type "1234" or any number greater than what I put as max, signified as _**m**_, for the second time.

Comment: I have an update; the while now is **"while(!isProcessed || count < none || count > m)"** and now, any number can be typed, and only the right ones get used. But if you type a really big number, it doesn't show "InputMismatchException". Help?

Comment: InputMismatchException will be thrown if the entered value is greater than the range of an int ( in our case). Anyways I've updated my answer which shows an example which checks whether the user input is within 0 -150. Please accept the answer if it helped you.